# How is it possible to receive data from an http request, but when you go to the http request directly in a new tab you get a 404 error?

Tags: firebase, http, web, httprequest

I am currently testing out the chrome dev tools specifically the Network tab. I am using firebase as my backend. I saw that I had a network request going to the location: https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:lookup?key=myKey (I have changed api key for security reasons). The network tab shows that the request to this URL has a status code of 200 which means it has succeeded in getting the information.

Now when I copy and paste this url directly into a new tab, I get an error code of 404 and page not found.

How is it possible for this request to receive data, but when I go to it directly in the browser I get a 404 error?

Comment: Are you sure you are sending the request with the same method? If you open the url in the new tab you will basically execute the GET request. But as per [api](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/reference/rest#rest-resource:-v1.accounts) the endpoint you are looking at expects the POST request. Well and if server expects only POST request on a specific endpoint - returning 404 status code or 404 page is a common or even default behavior.

Comment: @SergeySosunov that makes sense. It actually is a post request, but I just didn't realize it when asking this question. Thanks for the help!